# Weird behaviour while editing "Environment Variables"

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

If you take a look at the following screenshot, you see 2 very similar "Environment Variables" menus.

[image: Environment Variables menus]

The one the left was accessed by:

```
 Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables...
```

The other by simply accessing "edit the system environment variables" by typing in the Windows menu. Do you see any difference? :)

...

In the right menu, the editing for the variables is locked!

We tried to modify the variables in the menu on the left but somehow things wouldn't work (we needed to put something in the path, and this would not would effectively happen not even after restarting explorer), and the changes wouldn't be effective. The only thing that solved the situation was restarting the system.

Do you know what might have happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left window opened as administrator, because opening Advanced System Settings requires elevation. With default UAC settings you does not see elevation prompt for this, because UAC elevates Windows executable without prompt, but at least you should see UAC shield near to Advanced System Settings link, that indicate required elevation. Right window opened as user, so in it you can not edit system wide environment variables.